# Remove extra brackets in Sympy printing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy

When printing with Sympy certain symbolic expressions include brackets which may not be visually desirable.  As stated in the [Printing System Documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html), the `sympy.latex` function has an argument `fold_func_brackets` which will remove these brackets.

How can you get the same functionality when printing to the screen (e.g. in IPython-notebook or terminal).  For example

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
a, b = symbols('a, b')
cos(a) + sin(b)
```

The result of this is `sin(b) + cos(a)`.  However, I'd like it to print: `sin b + cos a` without the brackets.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no builtin way to do this, but you could probably modify the a subclass of the printer pretty easily, and pass it in as a custom printer to `init_printing(pretty_printer=Printer)`. You want to subclass [PrettyPrinter](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/07299f9276f6ce1f22d42f2e1b1cadad259238ae/sympy/printing/pretty/pretty.py#L26) and override [_print_Function](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/07299f9276f6ce1f22d42f2e1b1cadad259238ae/sympy/printing/pretty/pretty.py#L26) to be the same, except changing the call that uses `prettyForm.FUNC`.

If you want to add an option to do this to the SymPy printer, we would probably accept the pull request.